# Create a simple alias for route command

Tags: command-line, bash

I'd like to create a simple alias:

```
alias gate=route | grep default | awk '{print $2}'
```

and even though the command does work in terminal, it's not working through ~/.bash_aliases. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put quotes around the pipeline - being careful to ensure that `$2` doesn't get expanded by the shell. So for example

```
alias gate='route | grep default | awk "{print \$2}"'
```

or

```
alias gate="route | grep default | awk '{print \$2}'"
```

---

Note that `awk` can do pattern matching - so you don't really need `grep`:

```
alias gate="route | awk '/^default/ {print \$2}'"
```